# Error uploading new manifest.xml file to Office Store

Tags: office-addins, office-store

I'm trying to publish a new version of my Excel add-in to the Office Store. This is the first time I've done this since first adding the add-in to the store. I'm using the "Review and Publish" page of the Microsoft Partner Center website. Under "Packages", when I upload my new manifest.xml, I get the following error message:

*Error Message: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Ingestion.Shared.ServiceClients.ServiceClientException' was thrown.
CorrelationID: 554f85fa-edf9-4c50-9975-43cc5f83325b
App Server: PackageApi
Date: Tue, 25 Aug 2020 17:54:09 GMT*

Does this mean there is something wrong with my manifest file, or is there something wrong with the Microsoft server? The only difference between this new manifest file and the manifest that MS has already accepted is the version number and the path on my web server where the javascript and resource files are held.

Comment: Customer Service questions are off topic here. Please open a Customer Support ticket instead
https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 
1.    Browse topics Category: Commercial Marketplace
2.    Topic: Certification issue
3.    Next step: Review solution

Comment: Thank you. I have created a ticket in the Partner Center.